# Discord bot - Collect data from Dm

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I try to collect data in a .txt file from my bot DM:

```
client.on("message", async message => {
   if (message.content === "!whitelist") {
        message.guild.members.cache.forEach((member) => {
            if (member.roles.cache.has(staffID)) {
                member.send(`Hey ! Congratulation you are whitelisted ! Tap !address for whitelist your address :`);
            }
        })
    }

    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() === '!address'){
        message.channel.send("Enter your address : ");
        let counter = 0;
        let filter = m => !m.author.bot;
        let collector = new discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, filter);
        collector.on('collect', (message, col) => {
            if (message.content.startsWith("0x"))
            {
                fs.appendFile('/Users/mybre/Documents/Bot/test.txt', message.content + ",", err => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err)
                        return
                    }
                    //file written successfully
                })
                collector.stop();
                message.channel.send('You are whitelisted !');
            }

        });
        collector.on('end', collected => {
            console.log("address : " + message.content);
        });
    }
})
```

The problem there when I write `!whitelist` my bot send me a DM "Hey ! Congratulation...", but if just after I write `!address` it's not working in DM... That works only from my server.

How can I continue the step only from DM and not from channel of my server ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `index.js`, make sure you have the `directMessages` intent and the `CHANNEL` partial when initializing your client:

```js
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES,
  ],
  partials: ['CHANNEL']
})
```

To make the command only work in DMs, just check the type:

```js
if (!message.channel.type !== 'DM' || !message.channel.type !== 'GROUP_DM')  return
```